# Build Jenkins job with Build periodically option with different argument

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, multibranch-pipeline

I have a Jenkins job which accepts only `BranchName`(bitbucket) as an input parameter.

I have scheduled this Job to run every morning 7 AM with Build periodically option `H 7 * * *`.

On triggering automatically, it takes default input parameter as `development`.

Now my requirement is that I need to pass few other branch names as input parameter automatically.

One option I tried it Down stream job with other branch name, but that works only from one branch and not a sophisticated solution.

Is there an easy way I can achieve this?

[Job Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20L96.png)

Comment: Can you give a try using [Extensible Choice Parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/extensible-choice-parameter/)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to run a known set of branches you can either:

- Create an upstream job for every branch that [triggers the build with different parameters](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/).
- Create one upstream job, that utilize an list, loop over that list and [execute the jobs in parallel](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/#jobs-in-parallel).

If you need to get the list of branches dynamically, I would assume, that running `sh script: 'git branch', returnStdout: true` and some Groovy string split operation is the easiest way to archive that.

Comment: Thanks crash, execute the jobs in parallel helped.